# z-index refuses to work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make these black arrows overlap the white div, but they will not budge. I applied `position: relative` and different sizes of `z-index` to the div but they just will not work for any reason.

The closest luck I had was adding `position: absolute` to the `<div class="col-8">` element, which caused the arrows to overlap but broke the positioning of that div.

I have already looked at the many, many SO questions and responses about z-index not positioning above the respective, but no other solutions have worked. I have tried:

- using `position: relative` on parent elements
- changing the opacity to `opacity: .99`

None of those have worked.

How can I make these arrows work?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLfhe6xa/1/).

The CSS for the arrows starts at `Line 141` and `146`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to see [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/bLfhe6xa/1/), and the problem you have is the use of overflow: auto in col-12 class.

```
.col-12 {
float: left;
overflow: auto;}
```

If you remove that, you can see the arrows over the div, as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is due to the fact that the container you're using has an overflow set. To come over this issue what you can do is to either change it, or give to the `#nav li:after` a `position:fixed` and then change the `top` and `left` values accordingly.

A second approach would be to do not use the `overflow: auto` on the `#header-content`.